# Pregunta sobre pronombre: preguntárnoslas

Tags: pronombres

please look at the below sentence:

> Gabriela no quiere presentarnos a sus amigas.

(Gabriela doesn't want to introduce us (DO) to her friends (IO)) where DO is Direct Object and IO is indirect object.

nos=DO, a sus amigas=IO

Due to IO+DO rule, so the word should be "presentárlasnos" where "las"(IO), then "nos" (DO), no?

But why the correct answer is "presentárnoslas"?

Comment: You wrote a different verb in the title... :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the section 4 of this [link](http://buscon.rae.es/dpdI/SrvltGUIBusDPD?lema=pronombres%20personales%20%E1tonos). There you can read this:

> **Orden de las secuencias de clíticos**. Un mismo verbo puede llevar dos y hasta tres pronombres clíticos, que se anteponen o posponen al
> verbo siempre en bloque, no pudiendo anteponerse unos y posponerse
> otros. El orden no es libre y se somete, básicamente, a la regla que
> establece que los pronombres de segunda persona preceden a los de
> primera y estos a los de tercera, salvo a la forma se, que precede a
> todas las demás (se + 2.ª pers. + 1.ª pers. + 3.ª pers.):
>
> «Ay, Dios, que **te me** lo llevaste cuando más falta me hacía»
>
> «Cualquiera **se te** la llevará delante de las narices»
>
> no son correctas, por tanto, secuencias como:
>
> «No **me se** haga el pendejo, Balbicito, no me cojudee» *(Incorrect).

So the rule is that you have to follow **this order**

1. Pronoun "**se**"
2. Pronouns of **second person**
3. Pronouns of **first person**
4. Pronouns of **third person**

So:

- "**nos**" refers to **we**, it's a pronoun of **1st person**.
- "**las**" refers to **they**, it's a pronoun of **3rd person**

The pronouns of 1st person goes before the ones of 3rd person as it's indicated in the order, so it should be *"presentárnoslas"* and not **presentárlasnos*.

Comment: Oops, what a mistake!  I have a typo in the caption subject!! ~_~

Comment: To me, "presentárnoslas" sounds like "introduce them to us", not "introduce us to them", which is what the OP meant. But *presentarlasnos is definitely incorrect.

Comment: @MikMik you're right, "presentárnoslas" means "introduce them to us" though the question is about the order of "nos"/"las".

Comment: @Javi: yes, but the OP says "us" is the direct object and "her friends" the indirect object. I'll write it in English, to make things clear: "Gabriela does not want to introduce us to her friends". "Presentárnoslas" doesn't match exactly that sentence (by meaning yes, because the introduction is mutual), I think. But maybe it does, according to the link you provide.

Comment: @MikMik: What does it mean by " "Presentárnoslas" doesn't match exactly that sentence (by meaning yes, because the introduction is mutual)"??

Comment: @Cadenza: I meant that "presentárnoslas", to me, sounds like "introduce them to us" not "introduce us to them", which is what the question asked. However, since you introduce people "both ways", it doesn't matter so much. But let's change the verb and use "entregar". *Entregárnoslas* is "give them to us", but "give us to them"?